# Could not get unknown property 'main' for SourceSet container of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetContainer

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

First, I'm simply trying to get AspectJ to pick up my compiled Kotlin classes.  While trying to do this, I ran across a post that said the OP was able to get AspectJ to pick up Kotlin files by adding this to the end of their modules build.gradle:

```
sourceSets.main.output.classesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.toString().replace("java", "kotlin")
```

But that gives me an error:

```
Could not get unknown property 'main' for SourceSet container of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetContainer.
```

I've tried adding the `sourceSet` `main` to the android DSL container, and all of the code lives in `<module>/src/main/java/`, so I'm really not sure what the deal is.

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 24):

I'm having a hard time visualizing your project structure. However I was getting the same error recently (nothing to do with AspectJ though). The problem is that the main source set in `sourceSets.main` is unresolved within Android projects (it is a valid source set within Java projects, which is what I was copying my original code from). To fix this, I changed: `sourceSets.main.` to `android.sourceSets.main.` to reference the actual main source set within Android projects.

Let me know if this works out! And if it doesn't, consider maybe adding a bit more detail to how your project is set up?

Comment: I tried your solution by enable jacoco coverage for a multi module android app like https://docs.gradle.org/6.4-rc-1/samples/sample_jvm_multi_project_with_code_coverage.html but it does not work.